# React Native 0.27.2 - Super expression must either be null or a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to build a RN project with an online tutorial,
anyway the "super" error comes out with the following settings :

react-native-cli: 0.1.10

react-native: 0.27.2

[Error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K34pI.png)

[Code preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJObp.png)

**UPDATE :**

The import method was written in the standard of react native 0.24 in search.js and featured.js, and now it worked perfectly.

Comment: Please post the code in Featured.js

Comment: Did you try `import Featured from './Featured';` and `import Search from './Search';` instead of the `var Featured = ....` ?